# How to loop this object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How I can to loop this object below

```
"fields": {
      "summary": {
          "required": true
     },
     "issuetype": {
          "required": true
     },
     "description": {
         "required": false
     }
}
```

And get this result

```
res = ['summary','issuetype','description']
```

Comment: You may use Object.keys(obj) to get the object keys returned as array.

Comment: What research have you done and what attempts have you made based on that research? Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
const obj = {
    "fields": {
        "summary": {
            "required": true
        },
         "issuetype": {
              "required": true
         },
         "description": {
             "required": false
         }
    }
};

console.log(Object.keys(obj.fields)); // ["summary", "issuetype", "description"]
```

Comment: Please don't answer such no-effort, obvious duplicates.